# Is there any query string that I can use with the QUERY function to get a group-wise maximum?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I know how to use the GROUP BY clause in the QUERY function with either a single or multiple fields. This can return the single row per grouping with the maximum value for one of the fields.

[This page](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/filter-min-or-max-value-in-each-group-in-google-sheets/) explains it nicely using these queries and image:

```
=query({A2:B10},"Select Col1,min(Col2) group by Col1",1)

=query({A14:C22},"Select Col1,Col2,min(Col3) group by Col1,Col2",1)
```

[image: Google Sheets using GROUP BY]

However, what if I only want a query that returns the corresponding values for the most recent row, grouped by multiple fields?  Is there a query that can do this?

### Example

**Source Table**

| created_at | first_name | last_name | email | address | city | st | zip | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4/12/2022 19:15:00 | Ava | Anderson | ava@domain.com | 123 Main St | Anytown | IL | 12345 | 1.00 |
| 8/30/2022 21:38:00 | Brooklyn | Brown | bb@domain.com | 234 Lake Rd | Baytown | CA | 54321 | 2.00 |
| 2/12/2022 16:58:00 | Ava | Anderson | ava@new.com | 123 Main St | Anytown | IL | 12345 | 3.00 |
| 4/28/2022 01:41:00 | Brooklyn | Brown | brook@acme.com | 456 Ace Ave | Bigtown | NY | 23456 | 4.00 |
| 5/03/2022 17:10:00 | Brooklyn | Brown | bb@domain.com | 234 Lake Rd | Baytown | CA | 54321 | 5.00 |

**Desired Query Result**

Group by first_name, last_name, address, city, st, and zip, but return the created_at, email, and amount for the maximum (most recent) value of created_at:

| created_at | first_name | last_name | email | address | city | st | zip | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4/12/2022 19:15:00 | Ava | Anderson | ava@domain.com | 123 Main St | Anytown | IL | 12345 | 1.00 |
| 8/30/2022 21:38:00 | Brooklyn | Brown | bb@domain.com | 234 Lake Rd | Baytown | CA | 54321 | 2.00 |
| 4/28/2022 01:41:00 | Brooklyn | Brown | brook@acme.com | 456 Ace Ave | Bigtown | NY | 23456 | 4.00 |

Is such a query possible in Google Sheets?

Answer (score 1):

**Use this formula**

```
=QUERY({QUERY(A1:I, " Select max(A),min(B),min(C),min(D),min(E),min(F),min(G),min(H),min(I) Group by B,C,E,F,G,H ", 1)},
                    " Select *  Where Col1 is Not null ")
```

[image]

Comment: This isn't quite it.  In the example table, I have three unique individuals, as determined by name and address; two happen to have the same name. I'd like to get the most recent record (including email and amount) for each of the three unique individuals.

I've found that if I use `=QUERY(A1:I, "select max(A),B,C,E,F,G,H group by B,C,E,F,G,H", 1)`, then I properly reduce the data down to the proper set of individuals, but I don't know how to then join that data with the most recent record for each person.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is the formula you need:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SORTN(SORT(
     QUERY({A1:I9,INDEX(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(D1:D9,"(\D+)@")))},
                "where Col2 is not null"),
                                10,1,1,0),9^9,2,10,1),9^9,9)
```

*(**Do adjust** the formula according to your ranges and locale)*

[image]

For the formula to work we create the helper column
`INDEX(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(D1:D9,"(\D+)@")))`.
We also use `9^9` which equals to 387420489 rows, making sure that all rows are included in our sorting calculations.
Finally in our `ARRAY_CONSTRAIN` function we return the first 9 columns discarding the 10th helper column.

Functions used:

- [`REGEXEXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244)
- [`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)
- [`INDEX`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242)
- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)
- [`SORT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150)
- [`SORTN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7354624)
- [`ARRAY_CONSTRAIN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3267036)